# Applying Linq on DataTables in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 data tables in C# Say dt1 and dt2. I need to fetch records from dt1 which are not present in dt2 on the basis of a Reference Id and need to select multiple columns via LINQ.

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried already?

Comment: @MrinalKamboj you shouldn't have approved that edit. Don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sure thanks, but I improved upon the Edit

Comment: var results = (from DataRow dr1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                               where !(from DataRow dr2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                                       select cao["dr2"]).Contains(cs["OID"])
                               select new { col1 = cs["RefId"], col2 = cs["Id"]});

I have used this code but need something faster than this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var result = dt1.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(p => !dt2.AsEnumerable().Any(p2 => p2["id"] == p["id"]))
             .CopyToDataTable();
```

You have plenty of options. You can also try the [LINQ EXCEPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `Linq API` are extension methods to `IEnumerable<T>`, it cannot be applied to the `DataTable` directly, use `AsEnumerable` for `DataTable` to call `Linq APIs`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - Thank you, I forgot that part. I updated my answer.

Comment: Even now its incorrect, since DataTable's `AsEnumerable` yields `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, not the type `T` as expected. You need `DataRow[<ColumnName>]` to fetch a value.

Comment: This shall, though the complexity would be O(N^2), +1 for the effort and modification to produce correct result

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the `DataRowComparer` as per requirement, as I am currently only comparing `Primary Key` (replace with actual column name), check for reference, how to do it using multiple columns
[C# Errors when doing a simple datarow comparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361407/c-sharp-errors-when-doing-a-simple-datarow-comparer)

```
 var result = dt1.AsEnumerable().Except(dt2.AsEnumerable(), new  DataRowComparer()).CopyToDataTable();

public class DataRowComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Whether the two strings are equal
    /// </summary>
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
    {
        return x["PrimaryKey"] == y["PrimaryKey"];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the hash code for this string.
    /// </summary>
    public int GetHashCode(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        return dataRow["PrimaryKey"].GetHashCode(); 

    }
}
```